# How to get a cell in a column with csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

My question is when I for loop a file and using the index find to get the column.  e.g.

```
file1 = open(students_file, 'r')

    for line in file1:
        line = line.split(",")
        stu_first = (line[1])
        print(stu_first)
```

Now, this prints the output here:

```
57

61
92
51

51
```

The spaces are the cells that are empty. So this column is index[1]. I want just print out 57. I would like to note, I am not using module csv for a good reason. Also, no modules are used other than the os module.

The reason I want to do this is I want to get 57 and times it by another number in another CSV file (yes I have 2 files I'm working with).

Any other suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Ok sorry for the misconceptions. I'm new to python and am trying to explain the best I can.

So the output above is the scores of 8 students. The blank spaces are those that did not take the course. The definition I am trying to do is normalise these scores by the highest mark in that course. In another csv file the highest score in the course is 95. Therefore what I want to do is loop through all these outputs above and divide it by 95 to get the normalised score. For example (57/95 = 0.6, 0/95 = None) etc..

I hope this explains a bit more? If not let me know.

Comment: Didn't get what you want!!

Comment: what is inside of your file and what is your expected output?

Comment: you just want to stop when you reach an empty cell? or skip that?

Comment: You should be using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). CSVs allow strings to contain commas inside a single column; your approach would cause all sorts of problems in that case.

Comment: check if the value contains only spaces then skip the value? It would be great to elaborate your question with the expected output. We all here are just guessing your expectation

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it will only read first row in csv file:

```
file1 = open(students_file, 'r').readline()
print(file1.split(",")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want to get 57 like you said, you can just do something like:

```
print(file1.split('\n')[0].split(",")[1])
```